# css alignment issue with facebook and twitter buttons

Tags: css, facebook

I can't figure out why the facebook buttons are mis-aligned at the top of the following page
http://wishd.me/chovy/lists/507f8817a51102a137000001

```
<div class="social">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-size="medium" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
    <div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

The facebook buttons are a little lower than the twitter button.

Answer (score 1):

if you'll inspect the dom, you see twitter iframe has a height of 20px and the fb div is 27px height.

the are several ways to handle this. I don't like the both post above, because the .social .iframe rule also move the fb iframe 4px down. the other one is to messy for my opinion.

you can do:

```
.social > iframe { display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 4px; }
```

all solutions are not the prettiest...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div style="float:left ;margin-right:5px;margin-top:4px">
     <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1347008535.html#_=1350635993430&amp;count=none&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwishd.me%2Fchovy%2Flists%2F507f8817a51102a137000001&amp;size=m&amp;text=chovy's%20wishlist%20%C2%BB%20Movies%20-%20Wishd.me&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwishd.me%2Fchovy%2Flists%2F507f8817a51102a137000001" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-none" style="width: 58px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button" data-twttr-rendered="true"></iframe>

</div>
```

result

> [image]

Comment: that fixes it, but a bit hacky. I shouldn't have to modify their code at all to get them to display properly. I think there is a rule cascadding down into facebook markup that is screwing it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
.social iframe {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}
```

Twitter `iframe` moves little lower and all aligned well.

p.s. Your `.social` styles located in style.css line 445.